# Disabling multitouch in android

Tags: android, multi-touch

How to disable multi touch in android either by manifest or programatically?

Comment: If you don't explicitly implement it, why does it hurt?

Comment: You can't, but all you really need to do is write your app such that it only handles pointer ID 0. That effectively makes it single touch.

Comment: @hsanders I have tried modifying manifest with <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />

Comment: @Péter Actually I am developing one game which doesn't require multitouch & with multitouch it gets wrong input.

Comment: Please check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777435/disable-multi-finger-touch-in-my-app/22635434#22635434

Comment: Please check this link [Disable multi finger touch in my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777435/disable-multi-finger-touch-in-my-app/22635434#22635434) It might helpful for you Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `android:splitMotionEvents` or `android:windowEnableSplitTouch`

Comment: put android:splitMotionEvents on LinearLayout or any Parent layout your view (Button) is.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent this you should turn off [splitMotionEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#splitMotionEvents) or [windowEnableSplitTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnableSplitTouch) attribute inside ViewGroup were buttons are located.

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```