# Disable multi finger touch in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

My app uses one Activity to host several fragments. Each time one fragment is shown on the phone screen.The view of each fragment consists of several image icons.

Currently, user is able to press on two icons **simultaneously** with two fingers (with each fingure press on one icon). **I want to disable this multi-touch feature** on my app to allow **only one icon press take effect at a time**.

**I tried the following ways:**

**Way 1:** in my app theme, I added:

```
<item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
```

**Way 2:** In Android Manifest xml, I added:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
```

**Way 3:** in my Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Multitouch detected!");
        return true;
    }
    else
       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Unfortunately, none of my solutions work. So, **How can I disable multi-touch feature** in my app??

Comment: try to add `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` on your ParentView instead of on app theme. Not sure if there is any diffs, but on my apps, it works.

Comment: I tried, it does not work for me either

Comment: https://iosdev03.medium.com/disabling-multi-touch-in-cross-platform-application-xamarin-ios-xamarin-android-1254f0252141

Answer (score 41):

For case: you have multiple buttons and you want make selected only one button. **In parent** (NOT ROOT, just parent of child) of buttons, in its xml params add

> android:splitMotionEvents="false"

And that's it.
Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" <-----------!!!
    >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_main_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_main_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button2" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_main_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Btw. When you have 2 linearlayout with 3 buttons per layout, you should set this splitMotionEvents in that two layouts **and also in parent** of that 2 linearLayouts. Otherwise you will be able click only one button per layout (sum = 2 then). I hope you get it. :)

None of the other solutions didn't work for me or was too lame.

Comment: so its better to include android:splitMotionEvents="false" in all Layouts right!!

Comment: I would write it better but my English is still not enough to describe this complex situation :)

Comment: I am still running with same issue..any suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29072698/2624806

Answer (score 14):

Yes I also faced this issue once 
and I found solution that **android:splitMotionEvents="false"** 
this will work only to direct children of a layout.

**Example**:

Like if you create two layout A and B and 
In A you have two buttons b1,b2
In B you have two buttons b3,b4

both A and B are in Parent Layout
So first you have to clear that these buttons are not direct children of Parent Layout

In Parent Layout only have two children A and B

Than if you add **android:splitMotionEvents="false"** to Parent Layout
then multi touch will not work on Layout A and Layout B but it will work on every button b1,b2,b3,b4 because these are not direct children of Parent Layout

So , If you want that multi touch will not work on these buttons also 
Than you have to add **android:splitMotionEvents="false"** this to every layout separately

There are some cases :

1).If you only add **android:splitMotionEvents="false"** on Layout A
than you can not touch button b1 and button b2 at same time
but you can touch button b1 or b2 and button b3 or b4 at same time.

2). just opposite of case 1.

3). But if you add **android:splitMotionEvents="false"** on both layouts than you can not touch any two buttons on your screen at same time.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:splitMotionEvents="false" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I think it might helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could put user a `GestureOverlayView` around the whole screen and only allow the first touch event to be processed by the lower views.

You must set up an onTouchListener on this transparent view, that does something like this:

```
gestureOverlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListnener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
       // True means the event is ignored by the overlayed views 
       return e.getPointerCount() > 1 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code of your solution?

Comment: Thanks. but how does this gestureOverLayView linked to my fragment view then?? Where to define it? As I said I have one Activity which hosts multiple fragments. Can I define it in activity instead of in each fragment?

Comment: @Emil, Are you sure?