# How to allow single multitouch

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am writing an custom ViewGroup where I need to use only single finger touch and wanted to remove multitouch completely. I have checked with other option `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` `android:windowEnableSplitTouch="false"` but both are not working.

**EDIT**

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        DragHelper.processTouchEvent(ev);

        return true;
    }
```

Any suggestion !

Comment: why do you think they are not working?

Comment: Update question: Here I wanted to try single finger touch event but on multitouch it gave IndexOutOfBound.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your custom view.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Multitouch detected!");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that is true...but I wanted to map single touch event to ViewDragHelper. Please check updated answer.