# How to disable two finger touch on layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, multi-touch

I have tried below to disable two finger touch by putting in my fragment layout but did not work`android:splitMotionEvents="false"`
Also i tried below in manifest: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />` No help.

If anyone knows how to please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
gestureOverlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListnener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
       // True means the event is ignored by the overlayed views 
       return e.getPointerCount() > 1 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

You can put a GestureOverlayView the whole screen and only allow the first touch event.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this answer already there on Stackoverflow

[Disable multi finger touch in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777435/disable-multi-finger-touch-in-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code to check run time multitouch and disable it:

```
    private SparseArray<PointF> mActivePointers= new SparseArray<PointF>();

 yourlayoutname.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

            // get pointer ID
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

            // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
            int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

            switch (maskedAction) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                    // We have a new pointer. Lets add it to the list of pointers

                    PointF f = new PointF();
                    f.x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                    f.y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
                    mActivePointers.put(pointerId, f);

                    if (mActivePointers.size() >= 2) {
                        //DO NOTHING
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    mActivePointers.remove(pointerId);

                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```