# Prevent multiple touches after touching an item on the list

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a main activity with a list view, an `onItemClickListener()` event is associated to the list view and when I touch an element I start an `AsyncTask` that does some work. I would like to disable the other touches that the user could make to the other elements of the list during the async task execution and re-enable them when the async task ends.
How could I do?

**This is my activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private ListView newList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> newArrayAdapter;

    private MyAsyncTask asyncTask;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        newArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        newList = findViewById(R.id.pairedDevicesListView);
        newList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        newList.setOnItemClickListener(null); //need something like this
        asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
        asyncTask.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        asyncTask.cancel(true);
        super.onBackPressed();

    }


    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        Context context; 
        public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
            this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // do some stuff
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newList.setOnItemClickListener();
            //does not work or I don't know what to pass
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try android:splitMotionEvents="false" attribute of your ListView also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777435/disable-multi-finger-touch-in-my-app/15641505

Comment: Start loading the progress wheel in `onPreExecute()` and stop loading the Progress wheel in `onPostExecute()`. When starting the progress use `progressbar.setCancelable(false)` to disable user interaction while ProgressBar is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this in your **onItemClickListener**:

```
newList.setEnabled(false);
```

And then in your **onPostExecute** method write:

```
newList.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (asyncTask == null || asyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
        asyncTask.execute();
    }
}
```

Be careful with `onBackPressed`, or you may call a function on a `null` object.

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (asyncTask != null) {
        asyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```